# using geoscan pioneer mini drone for yolov8 object detection

Tags: python, yolov8

i am getting the fllowing error is there a way of first converting the live feed video from the pioneer minin drone to a format yolov8x wil accept because i keep getting the following error message

```
C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\deepsort1\.venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\deepsort1\deepsort1.py 
Camera CONNECTED

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\deepsort1\deepsort1.py", line 77, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\deepsort1\deepsort1.py", line 24, in main
    for result in model.track(source=camera.get_frame(), show=True, stream=True, agnostic_nms=True):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\deepsort1\.venv\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\_contextlib.py", line 35, in generator_context
    response = gen.send(None)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\deepsort1\.venv\lib\site-packages\ultralytics\engine\predictor.py", line 254, in stream_inference
    self.setup_source(source if source is not None else self.args.source)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\deepsort1\.venv\lib\site-packages\ultralytics\engine\predictor.py", line 228, in setup_source
    self.dataset = load_inference_source(
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\deepsort1\.venv\lib\site-packages\ultralytics\data\build.py", line 165, in load_inference_source
    source, webcam, screenshot, from_img, in_memory, tensor = check_source(source)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\deepsort1\.venv\lib\site-packages\ultralytics\data\build.py", line 148, in check_source
    raise TypeError("Unsupported image type. For supported types see https://docs.ultralytics.com/modes/predict")
TypeError: Unsupported image type. For supported types see https://docs.ultralytics.com/modes/predict

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I cloned the pioneer-sdk repositories and i tried using the frames_from_camera.py file which contains the following code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from pioneer_sdk import Camera

# Connect to the drone camera
camera = Camera()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        raw_frame = camera.get_frame()  # Get raw data
        if raw_frame is not None:
            # Decode data to get image
            frame = cv2.imdecode(
                np.frombuffer(raw_frame, dtype=np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR
            )
        cv2.imshow("video", frame)  # Show an image on the screen

        if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:  # Exit if the ESC key is pressed
            break

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()  # Close all opened openCV windows
```

but i am getting a file formart not supported error

Comment: Here is link: https://docs.geoscan.aero/ru/master/programming/python/sdk-scripts/circle_flight.html